# unable to update wget version

Tags: linux, curl, wget

I want to update my wget version to 1.22 which is currently 1.19 using the command :

```
curl -O https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.21.tar.gz
```

but getting following error:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to ftp.gnu.org:443
```

Doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: ... *why* are you trying to update wget to 1.22 by downloading the source code? And if you *have* to use the source code, why are you trying to download **1.21** instead of 1.22?

Comment: Unless you have an overwhelmingly important reason to use 1.22 over the 1.19 you already have, just stick to the version your distribution provides and wait for it to update. If the maintainers are competent, they'll have backported any actual security issues.

Comment: @Shadur  I want to upgrade my curl version and to do that i need to upgrade the wget version

Comment: @Aviator no, that is factually wrong. And you definitely will render your system inoperable if you simply replace the installed libcurl with a different version, so this whole endeavour seems *very* ill-advised

Comment: Sincere advice: **Don't**. Wait for your distribution's maintainers to package the update. Judging by the questions you're asking and the reasons you're giving, *you do not know nearly enough to effectively update manually* and you're going to drastically wreck your system if you try.